# Javascript works when alert added

Tags: javascript

In a javascript program, I am trying to fill a global 3-property array
object from data in a file.  The program did not work successfully so
I tried debugging, but found it *does* work when run using Firefox's
internal debugger.  So tried using Firebug, but Firebug froze up.
Falling back to simple "alert" insertions, I found that adding an
"alert" produced a successful run but with puzzling "alert" messages -
the array length seems OK inside the array creation subroutine but is
zero outside the routine.  Presumably I am doing something wrong but
mm baffled by this behavior so turning here for help (as a first-time user).
FWIW JQuery is being used to read the data.  Below is the gist of the program:

```
var nodedata = new Array();
nodedata = [];
// use routine to fill array
requestNodeData();
alert('POST requestNodeData nodedata.length=' + nodedata.length);
// create markers
for (var index in nodedata) addMarker(nodedata[index], index);
alert('POST index Loop nodedata.length=' + nodedata.length);
  ...

function requestNodeData() {
  var formData = $('#form').serialize();
  $.post('/cgi-bin/get_nodedata.cgi', formData, processNodeData, 'text').error(processNodeDataError);
  return false; // this prevents form button submission
}

function processNodeData(data) {
  var strings = new Array(3);
  datalines = data.split(/\n/);
  for (var i = 0; i < (datalines.length); i++) {
    strings = datalines[i].split(/,/);
    nodedata[i] = {
      'lat': strings[0],
      'lng': strings[1],
      'name': strings[2]
    };
  }
  alert('END OF requestNodeData nodedata.length=' + nodedata.length);
}
```

---

NOTES:
The "END OF requestNodeData" alert always gives the expected array size
Adding the "POST requestNodeData" alert makes the program work successfully !
  but the array size is "0", not the expected array size !?
The "POST index Loop" gives 0 if the "POST requestNodeData" alert is omitted
  but gives the expected array size when that alert is included

Comment: wrap your code in .ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an AJAX request to retrieve the data. This request is, by default, asynchronous.  What happens, is that you are executing `requestNodeData()`. This sets up the ajax request and sends it to the server. The script will immediately continue however and handle the data that it gets back from the ajax request async from the rest of the script.

Long story short. It'll execute:

```
requestNodeData();
for (var index in nodedata) addMarker(nodedata[index], index);

... (some time goes by) ...

and when the data from requestNodeData is ready,
it'll execute processNodeData(data)
```

The use of `alert` will pause the script (but apparently not the ajax request), which will 'just in time' fill in your variable. For this reason, it's usually better to use `console.log` to prevent alerts disrupting the flow of your application.

---

To fix this use the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method instead of `jQuery.post()` and set 'async' to false, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/cgi-bin/get_nodedata.cgi',
  data: formData,
  success: processNodeData,
  dataType: 'text',
  async: false
});
```

This will cause the script to execute the script 'in order'.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed help, which solved the problem.  Obviously I am not accustomed to having asynchronous processes.

Comment: PS: want to add that I appreciated the detailed _explanation_ as much as the code, since it gave me some insight into how code using such asynchronous processes works.

Comment: BTW it is still puzzling to me that the alerts appeared in the order I'd expected, not displaying any asynchronicity, I'd not thought of that possibility - i.e. first the "END of requestNodeData" alert appeared (with expected array length), then the "POST requestNodeData" alert (with array length iof 0)

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are asynchronous, so you can't process the result of it, just after the call.
alert "helps" you, just because it pauses everything after it from execution, and during this time, ajax successfully ends, end  fills you variable.
So you should do any staff with your nodedata, just in success callback